# Error installing virtualbox-6.1 dpkg error

Tags: package-management, virtualbox, dpkg

I am using .deb package downloaded from Oracle website, and I even had it installed properly earlier. But now there's not really any change to the system however it throws below error. Also I can see the icon of it in the menu but it does not open. Using Ubuntu 20.04.1
What could be the problem?

```
$ sudo dpkg -i Software/virtualbox-6.1_6.1.14-140239~Ubuntu~eoan_amd64.deb
Selecting previously unselected package virtualbox-6.1. 
(Reading database ... 240840 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack virtualbox-6.1_6.1.14-140239~Ubuntu~eoan_amd64.deb ... 
Unpacking virtualbox-6.1 (6.1.14-140239~Ubuntu~eoan) ... 

dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of virtualbox-6.1: 
virtualbox-6.1 depends on libqt5opengl5 (= 5.0.2); however:  
Package libqt5opengl5 is not installed.  
virtualbox-6.1 depends on libqt5printsupport5 (=5.0.2); however:   
Package libqt5printsupport5 is not installed.  
virtualbox-6.1 depends on libsdl1.2debian (= 1.2.11); however:  
Package libsdl1.2debian is not installed.  
virtualbox-6.1 depends on python (<< 2.8); however:  
Package python is not installed. 
virtualbox-6.1 depends on python (= 2.7); however:   
Package python is not installed.  
virtualbox-6.1 depends on python:any (= 2.6.6-7~);
however:
dpkg: error processing package virtualbox-6.1 (--install):  dependency problems - leaving unconfigured 
Processing triggers for systemd (245.4-4ubuntu3.2) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.36.0-1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.24-1ubuntu3) ... 
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.64ubuntu1)... 
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.17-2) ... 
Processing triggers for shared-mime-info (1.15-1) ... 

Errors were encountered while processing:  virtualbox-6.1
```

Comment: What OS & release are you using?  Why do I see *eoan* or 19.10 messages in your post?  The `virtualbox` found in Ubuntu repositories for Ubuntu 20.04 is also 6.1 (https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/virtualbox)

Comment: @guiverc it is 20.04.1

Comment: Your content is hard to read (I tried to change the quoting you used to {} code block, but it didn't have line breaks in it so you'll need to re-paste. In your post you'll see references to "*6.1.14-140239~Ubuntu~eoan*", *eoan* is the code name of Ubuntu 19.10 so that package should never have installed on a 20.04 system (it's for the wrong release; 20.04's code name is *focal*). You need to remove it (your output is too hard to read so there maybe more than just that)

Comment: @guiverc unfortunately I found only packages listed in this site https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads for ubuntu 19.10 and 20.04

Comment: As per my first comment, you could have just `sudo apt install virtualbox` and had your system automatically download & install the 6.1 version of `virtualbox`, the version tested for your release.  (the first link shows it's in `multiverse` repository, at most you would have needed to enable that repository, if it wasn't selected/enabled already)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I restore the default repositories?](https://askubuntu.com/q/124017/)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Read output. "dependency problems"

libqt5opengl5
libqt5printsupport5
libsdl1.2debian
...
etc.

```
sudo apt install -f -y
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me. I get the exact same error as OP, and when I run this command, it doesn't install any dependencies but rather uninstalls virtualbox: `The following packages will be REMOVED:
  virtualbox-6.1`.